# Getting error404 on Ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I have problem with my ajax code. I`m trying to increase number inside span on click with ajax, but keep getting error in console - POST `localhost/slots/game/lines` 404 (Not Found) . Btw, I use Codeigniter.

Here is the code :

PHP (Controller)

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Game extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){
    }
    function win()
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata( array('win') => $win);
        $win = $this->input->post('win');
    }
    function lines()
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata( array('lines') => $lines);
        $lines = $this->input->post('lines');
        echo $lines++;
    }
    function wager(){
        $this->session->set_userdata( array('wager') => $wager);
        $wager = $this->input->post('wager');
    }   
}
?>
```

And here is my Ajax -

```
function lines()
{
var lines = parseInt($('#lines span').html()) + 1;
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: base_url + 'game/lines',
        data: { lines: lines },
        success:function(response){
            if(response <= 8){
                $('#lines span').html(response);
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }

});
}
```

And in my HTML I call `lines function onclick`.I`m using latest xampp as my virtual host.I also have one custom route in CI -

```
$route['game/(:any)'] = "game/$1";
```

P.S. base_url is defined in JS as variable.

Comment: You can see the xmlhttprequest in the console right? What happens if you open that url in a browser?

Comment: Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again...

Comment: And your base-url is http://localhost/slots?

Comment: yes (http://localhost/slots/)

Comment: So the problem is with your controller. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html so the game class is in a folder called slots?

Comment: What happens if you do console.log(response) in your ajax success?

Comment: I get the same message..

Comment: HMR - no, file game.php is in controllers folder, and inside that file I have php function called 'lines'.

Comment: Could you try and remove the route? Theres no need for it as it is now.

Comment: And could you also try and log the base_url variable, just to be sure?

Comment: try: localhost/index.php/Game/lines I'm not sure where slots come from

Comment: Slots is the folder his CI installation is placed in.

Comment: var base_url is ok,route is removed but still getting that error..

Comment: And have you made a .htaccess file to remove the index.php and remove it from the config file?

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen Ah, so the url to test this could be: localhost/slots/index.php/game/index and have the index function return something to see if the router works?

Comment: -'slots' is my CI, I just renamed it to 'slots'
-I didn`t remove index.php, tried several times but couldn`t solve that so I left it (on other CI projects it works just fine with that index.php)

Comment: @HMR: Yes if he didn't use url_rewrite that should definately work for him. Please try that url mihajloWR (:

Comment: did - got the blank page

hmm..I mixed something..default controller is 'base.php' where I call my slots view, but not sure how I call my 'game' controller..

Comment: Ok then you did not setup url_rewrite, and that's why it's not working like you want it. 2 sec

Comment: How about posting in your javascript to: localhost/slots/index.php/game/lines so in your javascript: url: base_url + '/slots/index.php/game/lines',

Comment: If that works look under removing the index.php file here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: @HMR if I do that, I get error500
HMR after addig rewrite, can I remove 'index page' property?

Comment: it should probably be: base_url + 'index.php/game/lines if you included slots in your base_url. But check my answer, then you dont have to place index.php in front

Comment: Ah sorry, remove the base_url I left it in there by mistake when copying and pasting it. So it should be: url: '/slots/index.php/game/lines' later you can add variables in the url string but first see what fixes it.

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen http://localhost/slots/index.php/ shows page, but with the same error

Comment: CI folder is uploaded, if you want you can inspect it locally
http://we.tl/PVcIm7NGiO

Comment: No, that's ok. I don't have Apache and PHP running on my develop computer at the moment. You can open http://localhost/slots/index.php/game/lines in a browser without getting 404?

Comment: that gives blank page, no code in background or anything else

Comment: console.log(response) doesn`t show anything, and about router - can you tell me how to see if it`s working?

Comment: So if you changed the javascript to  url: '/slots/index.php/game/lines' it gives you 404? If that works then all you need to do is implement the mod rewrite and maybe add some stuff to the php.ini: http://www.terencechang.com/2008/08/28/codeigniter-no-input-file-specified-php-5-apache-2/

Comment: if you meant this : url: base_url + 'slots/index.php/game/lines' than yes, it gives error 404

Comment: What is your base_url variable equal to?

Comment: I've asked to leave out the base_url and hard code the full url so no other things can cause problems.

Comment: var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'
I tried with full url, still getting error

Comment: That sounds impossible, if you can open the page in a browser but the xhr gives 404 then you must have copied it wrong, here is it again:  url: '/slots/index.php/game/lines'

Comment: POST http://localhost/slots/index.php/game/lines 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Your javascript is placed in a js file right? So how can you echo echo the base_url? And in the file you uploaded the url in ajax is '/slots/index.php/game/lines', when it should be 'localhost/slots/index.php/game/lines'

Comment: Also you have a lot of syntax errors in your controller. $this->session->set_userdata( array('lines') => $lines); should be $this->session->set_userdata( array('lines' => $lines)); and you cannot use the $lines variable in that method call since it's not declared until the next line.

Comment: thanks for info, I think it is problem in my xampp. I have other version of that slot machine written in JS, and it works fine at work, but I tried now to start it here, and get error500, so it`s something about xampp. thank you all for your time and effort to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

As we found out in the comments your problem is the url_rewrite. Try this:

Make a file called .htaccess and place it in root folder, where your index.php file is (notice the dot in front). Write this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

In application/config/config.php the index file option should be empty empty like:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: POST http://localhost/slots/game/lines 404 (Not Found)  and it is pointing on jquery_v1.9.1.js:5

Comment: I can view page, but after clicking on that span, error comes in console

Comment: and if you type localhost/slots/game in url it gives you an empty page?

Comment: here is link to uploaded folder, if you have spare time to check it out http://we.tl/PVcIm7NGiO

Comment: no, I get 'Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.'

Comment: There is no .htaccess file and you did not change the index_page option in your config here

Comment: Well hat's what i told you to change in this answer. You wont get it working without if you want to remove index.php from the url

Comment: but I dont`t want to remove index.php..the thing is - that 'clicking' worked fine, but then I deleted/edited something in my controller/ajax and after that it started with this error thing..

Comment: Then the url for that method will just be localhost/slots/index.php/game/lines. Try and write that in your ajax!

Comment: if you meant url: 'http://localhost/slots/index.php/game/lines', than no, error 404 is present

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your routes:

```
$route['game/(:any)'] = "game/lines/$1";

refer to the codeigniter user_guide to learn more about URI routing.
```

By the way, are you using .htacess?

Comment: tried, didn`t work. I have simplifed version of this issue, check it out if you want. And no, I'm not using overwrite. So far everything wourked out good without it, so I don't think it is about that.

Link to new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378887/simple-ajax-codeigniter-request

Comment: did your base_url works? open the source code through firefox and see if your JS works. and look like this http://localhost/game/lines',

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to put this inside your GUI (view.php).

```
<script>
function lines(){
    var lines = parseInt($('#lines span').html()) + 1;
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url()?>game/lines',
            data: { lines: lines },
            success:function(response){
                if(response <= 8){
                    $('#lines span').html(response);
                    return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }

    });
}
</script>
```

to check your code make the url static like this:

```
http://localhost/game/lines
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Thank you all for trying to help me.
2. The final solution was to provide full path in ajax url, something like this `url: 'localhost/slots/index.php/game/line'`.

It must be something with the xampp, because at work (we use Linux and lighttpd) 'echo base_url();' works just fine, so I can write my ajax url path like this: `url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?> + 'game/line`.

Hope you won't get stuck as I did.

Answer (score 0):

If url_rewrite is not your problem and as you have told in last comment after question that you got `500 Internal Server Error` then it is because of your syntax errors in controller methods as below:

```
$this->session->set_userdata( array('lines') => $lines); //wrong -syntax error
```

Change it to as below line:

```
$this->session->set_userdata( array('lines' => $lines )); //Right
```

and i am writing your Whole controller without any syntax error replace it with your and it will works.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Game extends CI_Controller {
   function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
   }
   function index(){
   }
   function win()
   {
    $this->session->set_userdata( array('win' => $win));
    $win = $this->input->post('win');
   }
   function lines()
   {
    $this->session->set_userdata( array('lines' => $lines));
    $lines = $this->input->post('lines');
    echo $lines++;
   }
   function wager()
   {
    $this->session->set_userdata( array('wager' => $wager));
    $wager = $this->input->post('wager');
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use routes as follow : 
$route['game/(:any)'] = "game/lines/$1";

and also try to send full base URL to hit ajax request.