# Simple Ajax/Codeigniter request

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, onclick

I'm having some issues with ajax and codeigniter. I've already posted another question ([link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373474/getting-error404-on-ajax-in-codeigniter)) and I thought I solved it, but I did not so I`m asking someone to write simple code with ajax/codeigniter that will increase number inside div/span on click.

I`m trying last few days to do this, but constantly getting errors..My CI setting are :
 base_url : `localhost/test/`
index:index.php
autoload:url
default controller:welcome (I left it so just for this test)

I would be more than happy to have simple example to do this. I tried also, again, but without any luck. Here's what I tried this time :

Controller (welcome.php)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

function increase(){
    $increase = $this->input->post('increase');
    echo increase++;
}
}
```

JS (Ajax)

```
function increase(){
var number = parseInt($('#number').html()) + 1;
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'localhost/test/welcome/increase',
        data: { increase:number },
        success:function(response){
            $('#number').html(response);
        }
});

}
```

View (HTML/CSS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery_v1.9.1.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/script.js">            </script>
<style type="text/css">
#number {
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
margin: auto auto;
line-height: 30px;
border: 1px solid #999999;
border-radius: 5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="number" onclick="increase()">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using latest xampp on windows 7. Error that I get when I click on span - `POST http://localhost/test/localhost/test/welcome/increase 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Don't use the "fix" tag unless you're talking about FIX protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You must submit the CSRF token from cookies otherwise the request will be invalid, if you have CSRF enabled in config.php.

You can use this [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation) to retrieve cookies in javascript.
And simply pass it to CI.

> ci_token

and

> ci_cookie

keys may be different and can be found
in config.php

I would also suggest setting up a route for the request and using

> site_url()

over

> base_url()

```
var SITE = "<?php echo site_url();?>" // GLOBAL variable so your javascripts can be external
```

-

```
var data = { 'ci_token' : $.cookies.get('ci_cookie'), 'increase' : parseInt(number)}
$.ajax({
    url : SITE + "/link/to/controller/method",
    data : data,
});
```

Comment: No, I don`t have to do none of these. All I had to do is proved full path in ajax url. I believe it has something with the xampp.

Answer (score 0):

use `site_url()` of codeigniter

```
 function increase(){
   var number = parseInt($('#number').html()) + 1;  
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '<?php echo site_url("welcome/increase")?>',
     data: { increse:number }, //<--- here should be increase
     success:function(response){
        $('#number').html(response);
     }
  });
```

}

however, adding `http://` in front of localhost should work

```
 url: 'http://localhost/test/welcome/increase',
```

but it is always better and recommended to use `site_url()` if you are calling a controller in CI...so that this won't give you errors while when you upload it to live server.

Comment: is it site_url or base_url? I think it is base_url..
error I get : POST http://localhost/test/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url(%22welcome/increase%22)?%3E 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: `base_url()` returns the same thing as site_url, without the index_page or url_suffix being appended.

Comment: Now I get this error (if I put full path) :

POST http://localhost/test/welcome/increse 404 (Not Found)

Comment: you forgot public while declaring the function `public function increse(){`

Comment: you are getting the error now.. since you spelled your functions name worng... `increase` as `increse` in ajax...:) :)

Comment: No,not at all..error : POST http://localhost/test/welcome/increase 404 (Not Found)  is pointing on jquery_v1.9.1.js:5 (if that helps).

Comment: i can still see typo on your code..like `data: { increse:number },` and you are taking it as `$increase = $this->input->post('increase');` anyways this is not giving you 404 error coz that is page not found error.. make sure your url is pointing the correct path..

Comment: I fixed that in my code, but forgot to make changes here..
My current data is data: { increase: number }

Comment: Fixed it..Url in ajax must be url: 'localhost/test/index.php/welcome/increase', (note index.php), and I had 'echo increase;' instead of 'echo $increase;' in my controller. Thank you all for your time, hope you won't get stuck with stupid things like I do.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax, don't use external link for your JS just use internal.

Make sure that you set your $config['base_url'] = `http://localhost/test/` in config.php

```
function increase(){
    var number = parseInt($('#number').html()) + 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url()?>welcome/increase',
        data: { increase:number },
        success:function(response){
           $('#number').html(response);
        }
   });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery_v1.9.1.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/script.js">            </script>
<style type="text/css">
  #number {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

</style>
</head>
<script>
function increase(){
  var number = parseInt($('#number').html()) + 1;
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo base_url()?>welcome/increase',
      data: { increase:number },
      success:function(response){
         $('#number').html(response);
      }
  });

}
</script>
<body>
<span id="number" onclick="increase()">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First You should define your site base_url in application/config file then use this base_url with your ajax page call from where your call goes.
Suppose your `base_url` is  **`http://localhost/test/`**

```
function increase(){
   var number = parseInt($('#number').html()) + 1;
   $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>welcome/increase',{number :number},function(response){
          $('#number').html(response);
   });    
}
```

then change your increase function in controller like this

```
function increase(){
   $increase = $_POST['number'];
echo increase++;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function increase(){
        var number = parseInt($('#number').html()) + 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'localhost/test/Welcome/increase/',
            data: "increase=" + number,
            dataType: "text",
            success:function(response){
                $('#number').html(response);
            }
        });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this ajax in a .php file than you should do something like this to your url:

```
function increase(){
var number = parseInt($('#number').html()) + 1;
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url+'welcome/increase',
    data: { increase:number },
    success:function(response){
        $('#number').html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

OR if you are doing this in a .js file than you need to add this line inside your head tag

```
<script> var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";</script>
```

And than use this :

```
function increase(){
var number = parseInt($('#number').html()) + 1;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url+'welcome/increase',
    data: { increase:number },
    success:function(response){
        $('#number').html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Hope that it resolves the problem. However, its always a good idea when developing in the local environment to set the base_url in config.php like this :

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = $root;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
View::::::    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>css/jquery.js"> </script>
<style type="text/css">
#number {
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
margin: 50px auto;
line-height: 30px;
border: 1px solid #999;
border-radius: 5px;
}
body{
cursor: default;
}
</style>
</head>
<script>
function increase(){
var number = parseInt($('#number').html());
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo base_url()?>main/samp_data',
  data: { increase:number },
  success:function(response){
     $('#number').html(response);
  }
  });
 }
</script>
<body>
<span id="number" onclick="increase()">0</span>
</body>
</html>




Controller::::::
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this -> load -> view('sample_view');
    }

    public function samp_data(){
        $increase = $this->input->post('increase');
        echo ++$increase;
    }
}
```