# Ajax request in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have been trying to create an ajax request in codeigniter. I've seen this question: [Simple Ajax/Codeigniter request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378887/simple-ajax-codeigniter-request) but I wasn't able to absorb that as there were the answers in which people were using **PHP inside Javascript**. I didn't know it was possible, however I gave that a try but it seems like the PHP wasn't being executed.

So here are my questions:

1. **Is it really possible to use PHP inside Javascript,** or am I mistaken?
2. What's the **right way to perform an Ajax request in Codeigniter**? What I've tried is the following:

`var param = {name : event_name, date : event_date, time : event_time};`

```
            $.ajax({
                // As seen from the question here at stackoverflow.
                url : "<?php echo base_url('event/new_event'); ?>",
                type : 'POST',
                data : param,
                beforeSend : function(){ },
                success : function(){
                    alert("Event created! Feel free to add as much details as you want.");
                    namebox.val("");
                    $("#new-event-modal").find(".close").trigger('click');
                    window.location.href = "<php echo base_url('user/dashboard'); ?>";
                },
                complete : function(){ },
                error : function(){ }
            });
```

I know the possibility that I could hardcode the `URL` in the request but that wouldn't be a good practice!!

Comment: You have one chance to use PHP in JavaScript, and that is at runtime where you can write in the script at page load, other than that, AJAX is the way to go to communicate to the backend on the fly.

Comment: That's OK. But I don't think it'd (PHP in JS) work in case of external JS files! Would it?

Comment: create a JS variable in your view before you load your JS file. You can use the base_url() function there. Keep it simple

Comment: Is it really possible to use PHP inside Javascript, or am I mistaken?

Yes you can used it when its not external file. But when its external you can assign url to some hidden input and then using input id pass its value to url.

What's the right way to perform an Ajax request in Codeigniter?
Its on your requirements. But remember if your CSRF is on you can not used post method unless you pass CSRF token with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way for you to accomplish this is by using some jquery:

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    var l = window.location;
    var base_url = l.protocol + "//" + l.host + "/" + l.pathname.split('/')[1];
    return base_url;
}

var postdata = {name : event_name, date : event_date, time : event_time};
var url = getBaseUrl()+"/event/new_event";

$.post(url, postdata, function(result){
  ...alert(result);
});
```

or call it straight from JS by caching it:

```
<script> 

    var test = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"event/new_event";
    alert(test);

</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but that's the problem here How to get that `base_url()`. It's a PHP function...

Comment: ah ok.. let me get that for you, hold on

Comment: again thanks but if you're familiar with Codeigniter, `base url` is the one that I have set in my configuration file and not comes from the address bar.

Comment: I understand, but php will only be able to hande that, not your JS. In order for JS to handle that, you will need to come up with a JS function

Comment: Just as a note, base_url is a codeigniter function you need to load with: $this->load->helper('url'); if you want to use base url in JS, include this in your header: `<script>base_url = "<?php echo base_url();  ?>";</script>`

Comment: right, the only way to do this is by loading it to your view, but  if you want to randomly call it from JS on any page, the JS function would probably work best

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **dirty hack** that I was going to use:

1. **Create a hidden field** somewhere on the page and when this page loads **echo out the `base_url()` as the value of that hidden field**.
2. Now when you want to make an ajax request, **access that hidden field
   and grab the `base url`** and use it however you want.

Comment: Sure it would.. But there must be a better solution

Comment: you should be able to use it this way: var test = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"event/new_event";

Answer (score 0):

The right way is always the simplest way, there is no need to import Jquery in your client if you are not already using it.

**This is your controller**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die();
class Example_ctrl extends CI_Controller {

    public function ajax_echo()
    {
        // get the ajax input
        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

        // $input can be accessed like an object
        $password = $input->password;
        $name = $input->name;

        // you can encode data back to JSON
        $output = json_encode($input);

        // and the response goes back!
        echo($output);
    }
}
?>
```

**This goes into your client**

```
<script>
    // here's the data you will send
    var my_data = {name: "Smith", password: "abc123"};

    // create the request object
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // open the object to the required url
    xhr.open("POST", "example_ctrl/ajax_echo", true);

    // on success, alert the response
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4 || xhr.status != 200)
            return;
        alert("Success: " + xhr.responseText);
        };

    // encode in JSON and send the string 
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(my_data));
</script>
```

Comment: Just a note: like you see in the example there is no need to include the base_url anywhere if the view and the controller are in the same domain. You can use a relative address in the client as shown.

Answer (score 0):

### There is no better way to do this .

Php codes can't be executed from external javascript files.

Try any of these :-

1) base_url() is something's that's will not change , better store it in cookie and then access it in both server side code and client side code

2) you can store the same base_url() in local storage , it will be available in your external JavaScript files

Hope it helps you :)